# aiohttp web.response body as json

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, aiohttp

I have HTTP server on `aiohttp` with [python-3.6](/questions/tagged/python-3.6). How can I return `web.Response()` through JSON (from a `dict`)?

```
async def api_server(request):
    res = {"q": "qqq", "a": "aaa"}
    return web.Response(res) # <-- as JSON
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can use [**`web.json_response`**](http://aiohttp.readthedocs.io/en/stable/web_reference.html#json-response):

```
async def api_server(request):
    res = {"q": "qqq", "a": "aaa"}
    return web.json_response(res)
```

Furthermore the `json_response` has additional parameters, like:

> ```
> json_response(data, text=None, body=None, status=200, reason=None,
>               headers=None, content_type='application/json', dumps=json.dumps)
> ```

Most of the parameters are the same as the generic `web.Response(..)`, but the `dumps` is more interesting: it is a reference to a method that converts data into its JSON equivalent. By default it uses `json.dumps`. If you however plan to write complex objects to the client, you perhaps should alter that. For now it is fine however.

Comment: how can I add a header "Total" here? `match_count = len(matches)
            headers = {'total': match_count}
            return web.json_response({"matches": fdata})`

Comment: @binrebin: you can pass a dictionary to the `headers` parameter, so something like `web.json_response(res, headers={'Total': '1425'})`